# How to make my picture both vertical and horizontal center?

Tags: css, reactjs

I was using react.js to build a template website.

When I build the first component, I met the problem.

the problem:

the picture is not in the middle of the page(I mean in vertical and in horizontal)

I have already use CSS flex to make it in the middle.

Why my picture's position is not in the middle of the page?

Just put that picture in that circle.

How to do that?

Here is my Center.js:

```
 import React from 'react';
 import image from './images/5.png'
 import './Center.css';

 const Center = () =>{
     return(
          <div id="center2">
             <img  id="center" alt="center" src={image}/>
          </div>
     );
   }

   export default Center
```

my app.js:

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
   import Center from './Components/Center';

   class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
     <div>
         <Center/>
      </div>
    );
  }
 }

export default App;
```

my center.css:

```
#center2{
text-align:center;
}
#center{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
}
```

my webpage on localhost 3000

[image]

Comment: Please include your code in text format instead of as images. Move the `images` directory to the `public` directory instead, and write `src="/images/5.png"`

Comment: Have you tried adding `./images/5.png` this in `src`.

Comment: there's a good answer below. Besides that, `img` tag doesn't have a closing tag that's because `img` cannot have children. So it's a self closing tag `<img />`

Answer (score 2):

If they are static you need to import it:

```
import image from './images/5.png'

return (
    <div id='center'>
        <img src={image} />
    </div>
)
```

otherwise you need to move `images` folder to `public` directory, and access it by

```
<div id='center'>
    <img src='./images/5.png' />
</div>
```

And this is the CSS to make that image on center:

```
#center2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Sorry about that.You didn't answer my second question.How to make my picture in middle of  the page?

Comment: Sorry,it doesn't work.It is still the same in my second picture.

Comment: @Jacky remove that `id='center'` from `img`

Comment: here it is the `jsfiddle` that shows that this css should work: https://jsfiddle.net/nxgwmkz2/ make sure you don't have any other css referencing them

Comment: It become worse after delete id="center" from img.I want both in horizontal and in vertical the picture is in the center

Comment: @Jacky just updated the answer. Please let your css as i was in question, and remove that extra div in you `Center` component

Comment: Sorry,would you look at my question again.I just want that picture into that circle.Can you do that?